# ReferenceError: updateGross is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem with the javascript. Inside the console it write :

I have a drop down with tax class (20%,10%)
I have a field with price without taxe
I have a field with price tax update automaticaly if price without taxe it changed.

the console write : `ReferenceError: updateGross is not defined --- onkeyup`

there my code

the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tax_rates = new Array();
<?php
  for ($i=0, $n=count($tax_class_drop_down); $i<$n; $i++) {
    if ($tax_class_drop_down[$i]['id'] > 0) {
      echo 'tax_rates["' . $tax_class_drop_down[$i]['id'] . '"] = ' . $tax->getTaxRateValue($tax_class_drop_down[$i]['id']) . ';' . "\n";
    }
  }
?>

  function doRound(x, places) {
    return Math.round(x * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places) ;
  }

  function getTaxRate() {
    var selected_value = document.forms["new_product"].products_tax_class_id.selectedIndex;
    var parameterVal = document.forms["new_product"].products_tax_class_id[selected_value].value;

    if ( (parameterVal > 0) && (tax_rates[parameterVal] > 0) ) {
      return tax_rates[parameterVal];
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  function updateGross() {
    var taxRate = getTaxRate();
    var grossValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_price.value;

    if (taxRate > 0) {
      grossValue = grossValue * ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
    }

<?php

  if (MODE_B2B_B2C == 'true') {
    $QcustomersGroup = $OSCOM_Products->db->prepare('select distinct customers_group_id,
                                                                     customers_group_name,
                                                                     customers_group_discount
                                                     from :table_customers_groups
                                                     where customers_group_id != 0
                                                     order by customers_group_id
                                                    ');

    $QcustomersGroup->execute();

    while ($QcustomersGroup->fetch() ) {
?>
        var grossValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?> = document.forms["new_product"].price<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?>.value;

        if (taxRate > 0) {
          grossValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?> = grossValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?> * ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
        }

        document.forms["new_product"].price_gross<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?>.value = doRound(grossValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?>, 4);
<?php
    }
  }
?>
    document.forms["new_product"].products_price_gross.value = doRound(grossValue, 4);
  }


  function updateMargin() {
    var grossValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_price.value; // valeur net du prix
    var costValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_cost.value; // cout d'achat
    var handlingValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_handling.value; // manutention ou autres frais

    if (isNaN(costValue)) costValue=0;
    if (isNaN(handlingValue)) handlingValue=0;

    marginValue =  100 - ((( parseInt(costValue) + parseInt(handlingValue)) /  parseInt(grossValue)) * 100);
    marginValue = Math.round(marginValue,2);
    document.getElementById('products_price_margins').innerHTML = marginValue + "%";
  }

  function updateNet() {
    var taxRate = getTaxRate();
    var netValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_price_gross.value;

    if (taxRate > 0) {
      netValue = netValue / ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
    }

<?php

  if (MODE_B2B_B2C == 'true') {
    $QcustomersGroup = $OSCOM_Products->db->prepare('select distinct customers_group_id,
                                                                      customers_group_name,
                                                                      customers_group_discount
                                                       from :table_customers_groups
                                                       where customers_group_id != 0
                                                       order by customers_group_id
                                                      ');

    $QcustomersGroup->execute();

    while ($QcustomersGroup->fetch() ) {
?>
        var netValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?> = document.forms["new_product"].price_gross<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?>.value;

        if (taxRate > 0) {
          netValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?> = netValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?> / ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
        }

        document.forms["new_product"].price<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?>.value = doRound(netValue<?php echo $QcustomersGroup->valueInt('customers_group_id'); ?>, 4);
<?php
    }
  }
?>

        document.forms["new_product"].products_price.value = doRound(netValue, 4);
      }
</script>
```

the HTML code for the price with and without taxes

```
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="<?php echo $OSCOM_Products->getDef('text_products_price'); ?>" class="col-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $OSCOM_Products->getDef('text_products_price'); ?></label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
<?php
  if (DISPLAY_DOUBLE_TAXE == 'false') {
    echo HTML::inputField('products_price', $pInfo->products_price, 'id="products_price" onkeyup="updateGross()"') . '<strong>' . $OSCOM_Products->getDef('text_products_price_net') . '</strong>';
  } else {
    echo HTML::inputField('products_price', $pInfo->products_price, 'id="products_price" onkeyup="updateGross()"') . '<strong>' . $OSCOM_Products->getDef('text_products_price_net') . '</strong>';
  }


  if (DISPLAY_DOUBLE_TAXE == 'false') {
    echo  HTML::inputField('products_price_gross', $pInfo->products_price, 'id="products_price_gross" onkeyup="updateNet()"') . '<strong>' . $OSCOM_Products->getDef('text_products_price_gross') . '</strong>';
  }
?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
updateGross();
</script>
```

le js généré :
le problème peut venir de la ou il n'y a pas de valeur :

```
tax_rates["3"] = 0;
tax_rates["4"] = 0;
tax_rates["1"] = 0;
tax_rates["2"] = 0;



var tax_rates = new Array();
tax_rates["3"] = 0;
tax_rates["4"] = 0;
tax_rates["1"] = 0;
tax_rates["2"] = 0;

  function doRound(x, places) {
    return Math.round(x * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places) ;
  }

  function getTaxRate() {
    var selected_value = document.forms["new_product"].products_tax_class_id.selectedIndex;
    var parameterVal = document.forms["new_product"].products_tax_class_id[selected_value].value;

    if ( (parameterVal > 0) && (tax_rates[parameterVal] > 0) ) {
      return tax_rates[parameterVal];
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  function updateGross() {
    var taxRate = getTaxRate();
    var grossValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_price.value;

    if (taxRate > 0) {
      grossValue = grossValue * ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
    }

        var grossValue1 = document.forms["new_product"].price1.value;

        if (taxRate > 0) {
          grossValue1 = grossValue1 * ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
        }

        document.forms["new_product"].price_gross1.value = doRound(grossValue1, 4);
    document.forms["new_product"].products_price_gross.value = doRound(grossValue, 4);
  }

/********************************/
/*        Margin report   */
/********************************/
  function updateMargin() {
    var grossValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_price.value; // valeur net du prix
    var costValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_cost.value; // cout d'achat
    var handlingValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_handling.value; // manutention ou autres frais

    if (isNaN(costValue)) costValue=0;
    if (isNaN(handlingValue)) handlingValue=0;

    marginValue =  100 - ((( parseInt(costValue) + parseInt(handlingValue)) /  parseInt(grossValue)) * 100);
    marginValue = Math.round(marginValue,2);
    document.getElementById('products_price_margins').innerHTML = marginValue + "%";
  }

  function updateNet() {
    var taxRate = getTaxRate();
    var netValue = document.forms["new_product"].products_price_gross.value;

    if (taxRate > 0) {
      netValue = netValue / ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
    }

        var netValue1 = document.forms["new_product"].price_gross1.value;

        if (taxRate > 0) {
          netValue1 = netValue1 / ((taxRate / 100) + 1);
        }

        document.forms["new_product"].price1.value = doRound(netValue1, 4);

        document.forms["new_product"].products_price.value = doRound(netValue, 4);
      }
```

Comment: Why are you putting `<!-- //-->` around your javascript?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but on the very first line of your code you have <-- which denotes the start of a comment, meaning that everything following that is commented out, i.e. not executed by the receiving browser. I can't find the comment closing symbol which is --> so I think a significant portion if your code is commended out.

Comment: @ovimunt uncomment but the same problème

Comment: Forgive element : message write in console is : ReferenceError: updateGross is not defined --- onkeyup